# How to capture an image remotely using Hyper-V?

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I have a VM which I am accessing locally. To convert the VHDX to a WIM, I have found a number of powershell commands to do this and it works perfectly.

However, I want to do this when I do NOT have access to the host OS of the VM (i.e. I am working remotely). Would I need to do the same with powershell but running powershell remotely or are there other ways/tools to do this?

If you could list the options/steps that would be great.

I am building a custom Windows 10 image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have answered you won question. If you have PowerShell commands that already work to covert a .vhdx to .WIM then id stick with them. Either user Enter-PSSession to access a remote PowerShell session (you will need to make sure PSRemoting is enabled on the remote Host server) or use the Invoke-Command command to run a command remotely.

Invoke-Command
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command

Enter-PSSession
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession